# Configure Mocha to continually run tests fails

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to configure mocha to run the tests instead of running manually using the command:

```
node_modules\.bin\mocha -w
```

I get the error as below.

```
D:\Downloads\Bluemix\dw0015a\dw0015a\node_modules\mocha\lib\utils.js:626
    throw new Error("cannot resolve path (or pattern) '" + path + "'");
    ^

Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) '-w'
at Object.lookupFiles (D:\Downloads\Bluemix\dw0015a\dw0015a\node_modules\moc
at D:\Downloads\Bluemix\dw0015a\dw0015a\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:316:30
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Downloads\Bluemix\dw0015a\dw0015a\node_modules\moc
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
at startup (node.js:136:18)
at node.js:963:3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "configure mocha to run the tests".  Are you doing anything beyond using the `watch` flag?  Also, if you specify a directory after the `-w` flag, does it work?  (I know it should run in the CWD but...yeah.  Just checking...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get a behavior similar to what you report is to have the `w` option preceded by an "en dash" character (Unicode [U+2013](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)) rather than a minus character. Like this:

```
$ mocha –w
/home/x/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/utils.js:626
        throw new Error("cannot resolve path (or pattern) '" + path + "'");
        ^

Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) '–w'
    at Object.lookupFiles (/home/x/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/utils.js:626:15)
[... etc ...]
```

Make sure you are using the minus character (hex value 0x2d).

Comment: Here's a - minus for other users who have the same issue.i dint ve a minus on my keyboard.